# Is there a FSharpBinding Plugin for MonoDevelop 5.5 (latest)

Tags: f#, monodevelop

I would like to ask if there is a working FSharpBinding for MonoDevelop 5.5+?
The Addin Manager doesnt show a FSharpBinding to install and I was not able to find a package to download and install manually as well.
The addin repository to use does not work either.
(according to https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/wiki/Installation )

Actually it seems hard to get some current information.

The only option left seems to built MonoDevelop with FSharpBindings from Source, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: mono version? i've build it for 5.5 MonoDevelop and mono 3.12

Comment: @neftedollar currently running MonoDevelop 5.5 and Mono 3.10.0, but can try to get newer Mono

Comment: Try this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11022791/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding_5.6.0.mpack  Monodevelop 5.7, mono 3.12 Ubuntu 14.10 (it works!) it's my builded file. Or you can build it with this instructions https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/monodevelop/README.md

Comment: @neftedollar tried to get MonoDevelop 5.6 or 5.7 as required to use the plugin, but all PPAs I found are either outdated or lead to dependency conflicts (require newer libglib etc, which again is not found...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved when the F# Binding was added to the Addin Repository for the current (packaged) version MonoDevelop 5.5

for more information see https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/861#issuecomment-66513783